# Container inside row flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i need to make a row inside of it i write the date in square  then the tite of task and in the end of the row i added it a container in which i'm going to add the time .
but i get an error in the container
too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
can't we put a container inside the row ?
and as a design is it good ? how can i improve it i just need to show date task title and time

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0), //or 15.0
          child: Container(
            height: 60.0,
            width: 60.0,
            color: Color(0xffFF0E58),
            child: 
            Center(
              child: Text('27 juillet ' , 
               style:TextStyle( 
                 fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize:16, )
                  ,),
            )
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 20.0,
        ),
        Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Task tille',
              style:TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize:16,

              )
            ),
                       
          ],
        )
      ],
       Container(
             width: 40.0,
             height: 20.0,
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
             color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
             ),
             alignment: Alignment.center,
             child: Text('8/34' , style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 12,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,

                        ),

             ),
       ) ,
```

Answer (score 0):

No i just forget to close the ] of the row after the container that is the error

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so your return type is Row(), that means, once the children: [Widgets here] is closed, you cannot add more widgets later. So my suggestion is to make the return type of **'Widget build'** to Container() then add container's child as Column(), then use row within column's children.